# How to Replace associative array key with custom key ..?

Tags: php, array-splice

**I need to give output with 'floorno' and 'units' as key.But after performing array_splice operation 'floorno' and 'units' key are replaced by integer values.**

How to replace integer-valued key with text floorno and unit.

**Below is my code**

```
          $floor = "Ground";
          $query = "SELECT id,property_no,status FROM property_details WHERE wing ='$A' AND floor ='$floor'";
          $execute = $db->query($query);
          $ground = $execute->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $block_A = array("floorno"=>$floor,"units"=>$ground);

          $floor = "First";
          $query = "SELECT id,property_no,status FROM property_details WHERE wing ='$A' AND floor ='$floor'";
          $execute = $db->query($query);
          $ground = $execute->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $first = array("floorno"=>$floor,"units"=>$ground);
          array_splice($block_A,2,0,$first);
```

**Below is my array o/p:**

```
   {
    "0": "Second",
    "1": [
         {
          "id": "396",
          "property_no": "SSC.A.02.01",
          "status": "0"
         },
         {
           "id": "397",
           "property_no": "SSC.A.02.02",
           "status": "0"
         }
],
"2": "First",
"3": [
       {
         "id": "388",
         "property_no": "SSC.A.01.01",
         "status": "0"
       },
       {
        "id": "389",
        "property_no": "SSC.A.01.02",
        "status": "0"
       }
],
"floorno": "Ground",
"units": [
    {
        "id": "379",
        "property_no": "SSC.A.00.01",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "381",
        "property_no": "SSC.A.00.02",
        "status": "0"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: you just need this
$block_A = array("floorno"=>$floor,"units"=>$ground);
$result = array($block_A)
and then
$result[] = $first

Comment: i want output in the above mentioned format only..

Answer (score 0):

Helper function for splice with assoc

```
    function array_splice_assoc(&$input, $offset, $length, $replacement)
    {
        $replacement = (array)$replacement;
        $key_indices = array_flip(array_keys($input));
        if (isset($input[$offset]) && is_string($offset)) {
            $offset = $key_indices[$offset];
        }

        if (isset($input[$length]) && is_string($length)) {
            $length = $key_indices[$length] - $offset;
        }

        $input = array_slice($input, 0, $offset, TRUE)
            + $replacement
            + array_slice($input, $offset + $length, NULL, TRUE);
    }
```